# Access to DOM element with Vue method

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

1. I have a container who have inside many elements like h1, p etc.
   This container have a background, and I want create method to move him by mouse coordinates. I have a problem with access to this element, because e.target show me elements inside container, not container who is binded element.
2. Alive any solution to share all functions between main component and child components? Because when i want get this method in anyone place now i must add :moveHero="moveHero" to every component and get this in prop array,  so i want create this more globally in one place and share this to all childs. Now i think one solution for this is create .js file and import that to Vue.

Comment: you should have a look at https://github.com/Vivify-Ideas/vue-draggable

Comment: share some of your code to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `$ref` to the container element like this: `<div ref="container-ref">`.

Then to access the container element in vue methods, just do `this.$refs["container-ref"]`.

Explanation:

You can add `ref` attribute to any tag, even child components. It is parsed by vue only, browser ignores it.

If the ref is attached to a HTML tag, `this.$refs[key]` will return the corresponding DOM element.

If the ref is attached to a child component, `this.$refs[key]` will return the corresponding vue instance.